# Kohana, .htaccess and 403 access denied page

Tags: php, security, apache, .htaccess, kohana

How can I disable for viewing list of files inside folder for example

```
media/images
```

using .htaccess?

Of course, simple file with proper path

```
media/images/icons.png
```

should be available (all in all website need to use these files).

I have seen a lot of pages using such a thing.

I'm using Kohana v3, so I can  alternatively use routes and controllers but it's not efficient method...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the Options directive by turning off Indexes, e.g.

```
<Directory /media/images>
    Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

There's more information available here:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/misc/FAQ.html#indexes

Thanks,
Sean